# How to change this text to string to pass it to strings translation

Tags: java, android

I asked someone to developp an android app for me, but forgot to tell him to make the translation for me. I found how on google, by creating multiple string file in the values folder and translate almost all the app.
My problem is some text is written in the java folder. I made string for some but for others I can't. I tried using R.string.txt or @string/txt but it's not working. 
If you could help with those codes I would apreciate it.

1- in the first code the text I want to add as string is [débit à passer] & [gouttes/min]

```
final TextView txt = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.text_result);
    String  dose_qunt="Débit à passer " + "="+dose+" "+"gouttes/min";
```

2- for the second text: [please enter volume] & [please enter time]

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    hideKeyboard(this);
    if(view==btn_min){
        if(edt_vol.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){
            edt_vol.setError("please enter volume");

        }
        else if(edt_time.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            edt_time.setError("please enter time");
        }
```

Cordialy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a bad practice called "hardcoded strings".
Any strings that are shown to the user really should not be written in the Java source code.

That said, to properly correct such a problem, you need some understanding of Java and Android programming.

I can fix your specific examples with some guesswork, but if there are other such strings in your app, they may need a different solution.
It would really be better for you to ask the person who wrote the app to fix this.

That said, here how it should look:
1. Loading a string with parameters:

```
<string name="dose">"Débit à passer = %d gouttes/min"</string>
```

Notice `%d` is a placeholder for a value supplied when the app runs.
In this example the value can only be an integer. If you need different kind of parameter, like a decimal number, there is a list of placeholders [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

And this is how you load it:

```
int dose = 10; //just an example
final TextView txt = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.text_result);
txt.setText(getString(R.string.dose, dose));
```

2. The second case is almost identical, except you do not need a parameter:

   please enter volume

And the code will look like this:

```
if(edt_vol.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){
    edt_vol.setError(getString(R.string.volume_error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

R.string.nameOfString gives the id of the string.
What you need is to call getString and pass the id:

getString(R.string.some_text);

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this strings in values/string.xml in each language string file:

```
<string name="debit">Débit à passer </string> 
<string name="gouttes">gouttes/min</string>
```

And later you can use them as:

```
String  dose_qunt=getString(R.string.debit) + "="+dose+" "+getString(R.string.gouttes);
```

(for example)

If it dosen't works, write:

```
String  dose_qunt= getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.debit) + "="+dose+" "+getApplicationContext().(R.string.gouttes);
```

And simillar for the second texts.